# Inverted shading with polygons in QGIS 2.8

Tags: qgis, style

Is there a way to modify the style of a poygon .shp file so that **everything except** the polygon is rendered as shaded?

EDIT: see these images if you have trouble understanding. I am going for the effect in the second image.

[image: inside shading] [image: outside shading]

Comment: like setting the background colour of your map...?

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean — are you referring to the color swatch at  `Project > Project Properties > General > Background Color`?

If so, that's not what I want… OK suppose I have a DEM base layer and a semi-transparent hillshade rendering over it. I load in a .SHP file that contains a polygon which is a property boundary.

I would like to, for example, have my polygon rendered with a "line pattern fill" **exactly** like I am able to do via `Layer Properties > Style` **except** that I would like the entire visible area _outside_ the parcel to be shaded with the line pattern fill.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

You just have to do change the style of the polygon from "Single Symbol" to "**Inverted polygons**".

Here you can see a polygon with a solid fill using the "single symbol" style.
[image: polygon with single symbol solid fill style with a small transparency]

The top left of the style tab in the properties window for the polygon layer is where you change it to "inverted polygons".
[image: how to change it to inverted polygons stlye in QGIS]

Then you can hit OK and see it in the map.
[image: polygon displayed in QGIS using the inverted polygons style]

It's fun to experiment with other polygon "simple fills" such as shapeburst.
[image: an inverted polygons styled polygon using a shapeburst symbol fill in QGIS]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. …and I was sure that there would be a simple solution! Kind of surprised I didn't figure it out myself, but I never noticed that menu option.

Comment: Can this method be applied to multiple layers at once?

Comment: @corvus I would probably just build a .vrt of the files and layers I need, then apply the inverted effect to the vrt layer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the mask plugin?
Set the style to inverted polygon and set the shapeburst fill to transparent.
Set the layer transparency to the desired level.
Before mask:[image]
After mask:
[image]

Comment: I figured this could be somehow accomplished with masking, but didn't know I needed a plugin. Thanks for showing how it's done — Definitely more elegant than my original solution! …Do you know if there is a way to create a mask from polygons in separate layers, or would I have to merge them into a new layer before masking?