# Clip a heatmap made from point layer (not heatmap plugin) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, heat-map

So I'm just trying to make a heatmap based on 13 points I have which are the centroids for 13 regions in a country. The attribute of 'water percentage' is what I would like to base the heat map off of.

I've been working on this in arcgis with no love for some time. (Not enough points to create a strong krig or IDW output), Kernel density yielded a nice output but wouldn't allow me to extend the output further, past the points extent so it wouldn't cover my whole country boundary (geoprocessing>environments>processing extent; data frame set extent; properties>extent>set extent to another layer; etc. --nothing would actually change it). 
See Arcmap image below:

[image]

So I tried QGIS (which I have never used before) because I saw they had an easy option for making heat maps. I cannot use the heat map plugin because my data is vector (13 points) not raster.

What I've done is added my points as a point layer, went to properties>style, and changed it from single symbol to heat map. I get a nice output which looks good enough (still working to make it look more accurate)

[image]

**The problem is I need to clip this output to my country boundary and I can't seem to do this. I save it but it only shows up as a points layer again, without the style formatting. How may I clip the style formatting?

Comment: Also (just for background), I have this water percentage data for 3 different years so I will be reproducing this method for the latter two years to make a panel showing all 3 years and how flood extent has changed over time.

Comment: Do you need the clip for display purposes or for data sharing? (It's possible to create a simple mask solely for display purposes)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'data sharing', but yes, I just need the clip for display purposes. How would I create this mask?

Comment: Move the country boundary layer to the top and style it using an inverted polygon renderer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153754/inverted-shading-with-polygons-in-qgis-2-8

Comment: The inverted polygon renderer was exactly what I needed! What an interesting work-around. Thank you so much for this suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a mask for display, move the country boundary layer to the top and style it using an inverted polygon renderer, see [Inverted shading with polygons in QGIS 2.8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153754/inverted-shading-with-polygons-in-qgis-2-8)

Comment: that's my suggestion too... it works for us!

Comment: This was a great suggestion, and it worked perfectly for me. Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

Save your points as a .shp file (i.e. a point vector). The Heatmap plug in will then work for you.

Comment: They are saved as a shapefile. I may try this plug-in again, but for now the inverted polygon suggestion is sufficient for my purposes. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert your heatmap to a raster you should be able to clip the raster by a mask layer.

I'm not sure off the tip of my head how to convert your heatmap to a raster but the tutorial on heatmaps from QGIStutorials.com was really helpful and I'm pretty sure you get a raster layer from it. I did it a long time ago.
You could try the rasterize function but I suspect that it won't preserve your new heatmap as useful data.

Answer (score 0):

You could also edit the color ramp (under the heatmap settings under symbology) - edit "color 1" so that it is transparent or very low opacity.

[image]