How to snap Heatmap to outline of an island in QGIS
I am creating a heatmap of seabird nest locations on an island. However, some birds nest close to the coast, and part of the heat map extends into the ocean. How do I 'snap' the heatmap to fit the island's coastline?
I have created the heatmap in QGIS using Raster Density- Styled Heatmap (Kernel Density Estimation) tool.

Hi Michelle, welcome to GIS SE! Do you mean snapping or clipping? To clip the heatmap display: Use your island polygon to the top and display it as an inverted polygon, as suggested here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185493/clip-a-heatmap-made-from-point-layer-not-heatmap-plugin-in-qgis. Does that already help?

I guess I do not have the lingo down yet, yes this is exactly what I need! Thank you for your help.

To clip the heatmap display to the island, move your island polygon to the top of the layer stack and display it as an inverted polygon, as described in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/185950/52808

Thank you so much
