# How do I clip data frame (without clip shp file) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip

How can I produce different map view that shows data frame according to a predefined polygon?

In ArcGIS, one can clip data frame (without clip shp file)  using the Clip options on the Data Frame tab of the Data Frame Properties dialog box. Clearly, I need to learn how this process (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqPPghMw4Aw) can be done in QGIS 2.18.

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to *clip* your data, and not to apply a mask on your map to hide information you're not interested in?

Comment: Actually, you are right, I wrote using ArcGIS terminology :). Although I did the mask, the result was not the same as I had with ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to apply the inverted polygon style to your predefined polygon .shp file, and fill it with the desired color/pattern.

[image: Inverted polygon fill]

For example, see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153754/inverted-shading-with-polygons-in-qgis-2-8).