# Exporting an inverted polygon in QGIS outputs a NON-inverted polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, mapbox, masking

I am trying to export an inverted polygon layer to a GeoJSON in QGIS 3.16.1 Hannover (using same process to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153754/inverted-shading-with-polygons-in-qgis-2-8)) but everytime I export and save it, the output is NOT an inverted one.

I'm trying to export the Madagascar layer...

[image]
[image]

And the output is this which is NOT an inverted polygon...

[image]
[image]

Here are the export settings if it could help.

[image]

I also tried exporting to shapefile which is the alternative acceptable file I can use but still the same problem.

I'm stuck on this. Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Your "inverted" polygon is just inverted in symbology (meaning you color the "outside" of the polygon rather than coloring the inside). When you export it you are still exporting the exact same polygon and as GeoJSON doesn't store symbology the exported polygon get a random color with a more traditionnal "inside" fill when you add it in QGIS.

If your goal is to get the inverse polygon you will need to create a polygon covering the whole world then make a hole in it with with your original polygon (trying to do this could give you unexpected result/not work depending on which CRS you work). If you just want to color the outside of your GeoJSON polygon just apply the "Inverted Polygons" styling to it

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will try to do the hole although this might be really tricky as I need to cross the antimeridian and creating this as you mentioned might not be what I expected. Will update with results. Thanks again

Comment: Also depending on your use case you may not need a "whole world polygon with a hole in it" maybe a polygon as large or slightly larger than your study area could suffice or you may use spatial operator to the effect of "not in" to work with the outside part of the polygon without having a "real" outside polygon.